# Creating a poll on a condition on a drupal content type

Tags: drupal-7, content-type, polling

i want to make a content type where people can create a question (title, body, picture) and optionally add a poll. If they don't add a poll, it shouldn't be visible in the question...

Is there a module in drupal 7 where you can add a content type in a content type? Creating a poll is a separate content type and my question content type also...

Best regards,
Thijs

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. This module adds a new field type (Entity reference), so you can link an entity as a field of another entity. Make sure to configure display options properly in case you want the poll to be shown as a form instead of as a link to the form.

Comment: It's almost good... This module only shows a reference of an already build poll. But i want the user to add a new poll in the question content type. So adding a content type within a content type...